# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, crud

I'm very new to Rails, MVC, and CRUD, and I'm trying to use the update method to change the amount of votes on a post. I have the following code in my Posts Controller update method:

```
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if params[:vote] == 'up'
        @post.update_column(:ups => @post[:ups] + 1)
    elsif params[:vote] == 'down'
        @post.update_column(:downs => @post[:downs] + 1)
    end

    flash[:notice] = "Thanks for voting! This helps us determine important issues in our schools."

    redirect_to 'Posts#index'
end
```

and I have the following code in my routes.rb:

```
OpenMCJC::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'posts#index'
  resources :posts
  match '/posts/:id/:vote', :to => 'posts#update'
end
```

After navigating to "/posts/3/up", it throws the following error:

```
ArgumentError in PostsController#update

wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

The request parameters according to the page are as such:

```
{"id"=>"3",
"vote"=>"up"}
```

Can you help me figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`update_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) takes two arguments. You are only passing one.

Instead of:

```
@post.update_column(:ups => @post[:ups] + 1)
```

Try:

```
@post.update_column(:ups, @post[:ups] + 1)
```

This may seem like *two* arguments:

```
:ups => @post[:ups] + 1
```

but it's actually *one* hash.

With the more commonly used [`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes), you can pass a hash:

```
@post.update_attributes(:ups => @post[:ups] + 1)
```

Comment: This has bitten me before. Sadly.

Answer (score 9):

As Mischa pointed out, `update_column` takes two arguments. However, I would discourage you from using this method. First, it skips validations which may not be what you want. Second, Rails has built-in methods for [incrementing or decrementing values](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment). In your case, you could change your controller method to something like this:

```
if params[:vote] == 'up'
  @post.increment(:ups)
elsif params[:vote] == 'down'
  @post.increment(:downs)
end
```

Comment: Yeah, he should use those methods: +1