# what is this error in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sorry for this question.
tks for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813957/argumenterror-wrong-number-of-arguments-1-for-2)

Comment: can you post the method that gives that error?

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate of the nominated examplar.  That question is about a specific method call in a Rails app; this question appears to be about how to interpret ArgumentError exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's the same, but the numbers tell you what it is expecting. If the method was like the below, so two required arguments and one optional:

```
def test_method(arg1, arg2, arg3 = 1)
  // code
end
```

If you then call the following with no arguments:

```
test_method
```

You would see that exact message. It says you either need to give it 2 or all 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is the same error, the thing here is that if you see

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

it says that it needs 1 argument and have 0

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
```

in this it says that it needs 2 or 3 parameters and have 0.

```
2..3
```

is a range, so if you see 2..5 it says that it can have 2,3,4 or 5 parameters

Answer (score 0):

Ruby interpreter checks how many arguments takes `method` and if you call this `method` will different number of arguments, interpreter will raise `ArgumentError`.

```
def summ(a, b)
  a + b
end
```

Calling with one argument => `summ(1)` will raise error.